# Get rid of `N` using `modelsummary::datasummary_balance` in `R`

Tags: r, modelsummary

I'm using `datasummary_balance` and it works amazing...except it gives me the number of observations between treated and control. This is usually great but I have clusters so the number and the number of observations do not reflect the number of clusters. Any idea how to fix this?[Troublesome N](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4Zbn.png). Thanks in advance.

For clarification, I want to change the header on the table to not have N=...

Comment: For clarification, I want to change the header on the table to not have N=...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is currently no way to remove the number of observations in the column labels. The intention is for members of the `datasummary_*` family of functions to act as ready-made "templates", and for users to use the basic `datasummary()` function when they need to customize more extensively.

That said, depending on your output format, it can be trivial to remove
the observation number using a simple regular expression.

LaTeX:

```r
library(modelsummary)
library(magrittr)
dat = mtcars[, c("am", "hp", "mpg")]
dat$am = as.character(dat$am)

datasummary_balance(~am, output = "latex", data = dat) %>%
    gsub("\\(N=\\d*\\)", "", .)

# \begin{table}
# \centering
# \begin{tabular}[t]{lrrrrrr}
# \toprule
# \multicolumn{1}{c}{ } & \multicolumn{2}{c}{0 } & \multicolumn{2}{c}{1 } & \multicolumn{2}{c}{ } \\
# \cmidrule(l{3pt}r{3pt}){2-3} \cmidrule(l{3pt}r{3pt}){4-5}
#   & Mean & Std. Dev. & Mean  & Std. Dev.  & Diff. in Means & Std. Error\\
# \midrule
# hp & 160.3 & 53.9 & 126.8 & 84.1 & \num{-33.4} & \num{26.4}\\
# mpg & 17.1 & 3.8 & 24.4 & 6.2 & \num{7.2} & \num{1.9}\\
# \bottomrule
# \end{tabular}
# \end{table}
```

HTML:

```r
datasummary_balance(~am, output = "html", data = dat) %>%
    gsub("\\(N=\\d*\\)", "", .)

# <table class="table" style="width: auto !important; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
#  <thead>
# <tr>
# <th style="empty-cells: hide;border-bottom:hidden;" colspan="1"></th>
# <th style="border-bottom:hidden;padding-bottom:0; padding-left:3px;padding-right:3px;text-align: center; " colspan="2"><div style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd; padding-bottom: 5px; ">0 </div></th>
# <th style="border-bottom:hidden;padding-bottom:0; padding-left:3px;padding-right:3px;text-align: center; " colspan="2"><div style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd; padding-bottom: 5px; ">1 </div></th>
# <th style="empty-cells: hide;border-bottom:hidden;" colspan="2"></th>
# </tr>
#   <tr>
#    <th style="text-align:left;">   </th>
#    <th style="text-align:right;"> Mean </th>
#    <th style="text-align:right;"> Std. Dev. </th>
#    <th style="text-align:right;"> Mean  </th>
#    <th style="text-align:right;"> Std. Dev.  </th>
#    <th style="text-align:right;"> Diff. in Means </th>
#    <th style="text-align:right;"> Std. Error </th>
#   </tr>
#  </thead>
# <tbody>
#   <tr>
#    <td style="text-align:left;"> hp </td>
#    <td style="text-align:right;"> 160.3 </td>
#    <td style="text-align:right;"> 53.9 </td>
#    <td style="text-align:right;"> 126.8 </td>
#    <td style="text-align:right;"> 84.1 </td>
#    <td style="text-align:right;"> −33.4 </td>
#    <td style="text-align:right;"> 26.4 </td>
#   </tr>
#   <tr>
#    <td style="text-align:left;"> mpg </td>
#    <td style="text-align:right;"> 17.1 </td>
#    <td style="text-align:right;"> 3.8 </td>
#    <td style="text-align:right;"> 24.4 </td>
#    <td style="text-align:right;"> 6.2 </td>
#    <td style="text-align:right;"> 7.2 </td>
#    <td style="text-align:right;"> 1.9 </td>
#   </tr>
# </tbody>
# </table>
```